# How do I solve $\int \frac{x\cos^2x + \sin x}{\cos^2x} e^{\sin x} dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I tried the following:

1. Breaking up the fraction and applying parts to each of them.
2. Multiplying and dividing by $\cos x$ and performing substitutions and parts
3. Breaking up into fractions, performing substitution and adding and subtracting by the differential of the former half, hoping that differentiating that would give the latter half.

I couldn't get an answer.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this is the integral you wish to find? Carefully check what you have written for your integrand as a small typo could mean the world of difference between being able to find the integral in terms of elementary functions or not.

Comment: This is exactly the same integrand given in my workbook. So probably there is a printing mistake.

Comment: I believe as written your integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. If I make two very small changes in the integrand the resulting integral can be found in terms of elementary functions. The *changed* integral to find is: $$\int \frac{\color{red} - x \cos^{\color{red} 3} x + \sin x}{\cos^2 x} e^{\sin x} \, dx$$

Comment: Thanks. I'll work on that, then.